# Is it possible to apply hill-climbing algorithm to Diffie–Hellman?

Tags: algorithm-design, diffie-hellman

If Eve intercepts all the values communicated between Alice and Bob in a [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), and applies the [hill-climbing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) to reverse the modulo function, how will the algorithm know whether it is following the right path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NO**, we can't apply an hill-climbing algorithm to Diffie–Hellman.

In order to break [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) key exchange, it is enough for Eve to reverse ***exponentiation*** modulo the public prime $p$; that is, given $g^x\bmod p$, find $x$. That's the [Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm).

We do not know that [hill-climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) can help for that (or the slightly less general DH problem). One reason is that in the DLP, we have no known way to estimate if a guess of $x$ is close or far from the solution (contrary to what happens for the continuous logarithm problem). Hill-climbing is nice *when it works*; but in crypto, it tends to work only against weak/broken systems.

Comment: Well, you're not saying a complete no, it's just "We do not know". antilogs can be estimated by trial and error and maybe even hill climb. Isn't it a similar situation?

Comment: @Faraaz Ahmad: I've revised the answer towards a square NO, with as justification that we know no mean. Definitely, the situation is very different from that of the continuous case.

Answer (score 2):

Because groups used for Diffie-Hellman cannot be given a non-trivial, efficiently calculable metric, you cannot define such things like a "local maximum" or "local minimum". You also cannot say if you are climbing or diving.

Comment: Actually, it's quite easy to give them a metric with the actual solution as a local maximum.  What's difficult is to give a metric that gives a useful indication of "you're close"

Comment: @poncho: it's easy to define a metric that tells you when you're close, it's just that evaluating the metric is as hard as solving the discrete logarithm, so you don't get any benefit.

Comment: Corrected the aanswer. Thank you for making this precise.